# Однородные и неоднородные определения. Давайте разберем

Tags: определения, однородные-члены

Я прочитал статью об однородных и неоднородных определениях. Ниже — некоторые моменты, которые я никак не могу ясно понять. Помогите разобраться.
1. Обозначают субъективную характеристику (факультативный признак): маленькое, золотистое облачко; длинный, узкий ковер. Ну как же? Маленькое — относительное, золотистое — качественное. Следовательно, они никак не могут быть однородными, ведь так? Во втором случае также, например среди "узких ковров" можно выделить "длинные" и "короткие". Хотя согласен, выражают форму. Но все же, разъясните по подробней.
2. Обозначают взаимозависимые в условиях контекста признаки (= так как, поэтому) лунный; ясный вечер (= ясный, потому что лунный); опять же качественное с относительным.
3. Например: *В комнату вбежала маленькая громко смеющаяся девочка*. Почему же в этом случае нет запятой после "маленькая", ведь причастный оборот обособляется?
4. Обозначают синонимичные в условиях контекста признаки, при этом в условиях контекста они объединяются каким-нибудь общим признаком (сходством производимого ими впечатления, внешним видом и т. д.): *Он протягивал мне красную, опухшую, грязную руку*; *Тяжелые, холодные тучи лежали на вершинах окрестных гор*; *В густых, темных волосах блестели седые пряди*; *бледное, строгое лицо; веселый, добродушный смех; пустынный, неприветливый дом; ласковые, живые глаза; гордый, храбрый вид; сухие, потрескавшиеся губы; тяжелое, злое чувство; серый, непрерывный, мелкий дождь* и т.д.  Вот тут самое главное и непонятное для меня.  Ведь я часто допускаю ошибки в текстах, считая, что определения являются синонимичными в данном контексте. Вот только последние:
И странный тёмный воздух. Ну и почему же они не являются синонимичными,  а бледное, строгое лицо является?

Comment: Думаю, многие (но не все) пары могут считаться как однородными, так и неоднородными - в зависимости от авторской позиции.

Answer (score 1):

Всю теорию вы уже изложили, нет смысла повторять, но можно сказать, на что стоит обратить внимание.

1) **Однородные члены (любые) раскрывают общую тему и для них характерна перечислительная интонация.** Неоднородные члены называют **разные признаки,** причем первое определение относится к сочетанию второго определения и определяемого слова. **Перечислительной интонации нет.**

2) **Обращайте внимание на слова-метафоры**, они обычно входят в однородный ряд (тяжелое, злое чувство).

3) **Странный темный воздух; бледное, строгое лицо**

Всегда желательно работать с полным текстом.

Он как будто помнил холодок земли, зеленые сумерки леса, излуки тропинки, пересеченной там и сям горбатым корнем, мелькание стволов, мимо которых он босиком бежал, и **странный темный воздух,** полный сказочных возможностей (В. Набоков).

Назавтра вышел дежурный капитан Тиунов, прямо направился к Сучкову. Капитан – сухощавый, с **бледным, строгим лицом** и тонкими бровями.

Темный (сумеречный) воздух показался мальчику странным. Здесь разные признаки, нет сближения. У прилагательного *тёмный* прямое значение.

С бледным, строгим лицом. А это сближенные признаки, общее впечатление о внешности человека, по которым угадывается его характер.

4) **Маленькая громко смеющаяся девочка**.  Происхождение неизвестно (может быть, придуманный учебный пример), но я  бы поставила здесь запятую, так как определение стоит перед определительным оборотом: маленькая, громко смеющаяся девочка.

5) **В небе таяло одно маленькое, золотистое облачко.**

Через несколько минут я простился и ушел, лукавая баба, притворяя за мною дверь будки, ущипнула меня, говоря:
- Облака-то какие красные - огонь!
В небе таяло одно маленькое, золотистое облако.

Авторское сближение признаков (противопоставляются две картины?). Также возможно влияние слова *одно* (какое именно? следует перечисление признаков).

В другом тексте эти определения могут быть неоднородными, например:  Только маленькое золотистое облако плывет по небу.

Comment: А что насчёт "длинного, узкого ковра"?

Comment: Обычно это неоднородные определения, поэтому надо найти реальный текст с запятыми, например: "В передней на стене висел длинный, узкий ковер, на котором красовались две базилики Сан-Пьетро". Здесь  авторское сближение по внешнему виду (тем более что качества обычно сопутствующие), перечислительная интонация возможна.  Сравнить: Мне нужно купить длинный узкий ковер. Таким образом, эти определения могут быть однородными иди неоднородными в разных ситуациях.  К примеру,  после определяемого слова они считаются однородными по грамматической структуре: ковёр длинный, узкий.